# Why is the trailing linefeed being removed from variables in Bash in most cases?

Tags: bash

I am struggling to understand why a trailing linefeed is retained in only one of the following cases. See the script:

```
declare -a B

B[1]='foo'
B[2]=$'foo\n'
B[3]="$( echo 'foo' )"
B[4]="$( echo -e 'foo\n' )"
B[5]="$( printf '%s\n' 'foo' )"
B[6]="$( cat <<END
foo

END
       )"

# Print each value.
for RESULT in "${B[@]}"
do
        echo "[${RESULT}]"
done
```

And the result when run:

```
[foo]
[foo
]
[foo]
[foo]
[foo]
[foo]
```

I was expecting the first to lack a newline; the fourth and sixth to have two newlines each; and the others to have a single newline each. But instead, only the second has a newline.

What's going on, please?

Comment: Also see: [U&L: Why does shell Command Substitution gobble up a trailing newline char?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/17747/70524), [U&L: Where has the trailing newline char gone from my command substitution?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17732/where-has-the-trailing-newline-char-gone-from-my-command-substitution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented in `man bash` under *Command Substitution*, bold emphasis mine:

> *Bash* performs the expansion by executing `command` and replacing the command substitution  with  the  standard output of the command, **with any trailing newlines deleted**.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that. Thank you!